# Adding new parameter to current URL using JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, url, jstl

My application allows user to change language in any given moment and that cause me some trouble. For example if user specify page by URL: `/category/8?page=3` and then would try to change the language by `?language=en` it will erase previous parameters and take him to first page.

How can I get a current URL and add another parameter to it? I'd like to achieve something like this: `/category/8?page=3&language=en` when current ULR is `/category/8?page=3` and user tried to change a language.

I tried using `${pageContext.request.requestURL}` but that's not what I look for as it returns jsp page.

Comment: what did you try so far? what does your code look like? answers would be completely opinion based. without providing further information your question is likely to get closed.

Comment: I've updated post with the thing I tried but don't really know what else could I write. Problem's pretty simple - after clicking on a link I want to add another paramether to current URL like as I wrote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a tag file I use. Save it as `/WEB-INF/tags/replaceParam.tag`:

```
<%@ tag pageEncoding="UTF-8" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ attribute name="name" required="true" type="java.lang.String" %>
<%@ attribute name="value" required="true" type="java.lang.String" %>

<c:url value="">

    <%-- 
      replaces or adds a param to a URL
      if $name in query then replace its value with $value. 
      copies existing 
    --%>

    <c:forEach items="${paramValues}" var="p">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${p.key == name}">
                <c:param name="${name}" value="${value}"/>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <c:forEach items="${p.value}" var="val">
                    <c:param name="${p.key}" value="${val}"/>
                </c:forEach>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>

    <%-- if $name not in query, then add --%>
    <c:if test="${empty param[name] }">
        <c:param name="${name}" value="${value}"/>
    </c:if>

</c:url>
```

Usage in another page (ex url is `/category/9?page=3`):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="my" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<my:replaceParam name='language' value='en' />
```

output is `/category/9?page=3&language=en`